# CodeIgniter elegant library for sorting, paging and filtering

Tags: codeigniter, sorting, pagination, filtering

I am searching for an elegant library/spark for CodeIgniter that offers you the option to set pagination, filtering and sorting without to much hassle and independent from the database query.

I am already using a pagination library made by me a while ago, very easy to use, but I'm searching for something that extends to sorting and filtering as well.

Any resource is much appreciated.

**UPDATE**: I have actually found a great solution that works in Codeigniter, but not limited to. It supports ajax, server-side procesing, individual column filtering (which I needed by the way) and everything you need regarding pagination, sorting and filtering: [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net)

I also found an implementation with CI on Github, maybe this will be helpful to somebody: https://github.com/blake-nouribekian/codeigniter-datatables/blob/master/index.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Carbogrid](http://carbogrid.com/). This is so cool and easy to integrate

Comment: hi @Bhuvan, can you point how the filter works there? It doesn't seem to work for me:http://carbogrid.com/index.php/sample/single

Comment: @despina that is used to search as a whole instead of column filters.. Just mention some keyword in the text field provided on top of any column,mention a search type and click filter.. You can see it working

Comment: I can see it working now

Answer (score 1):

You can try these both are good

[JQgrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) or  [ExtJs](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/grid/paging.html)

Comment: thank, but I was looking something that would work server-side